# PrimeFaces showing one item of list on a row

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using datatable to retrieve records from database. Datatable is showing all the items on rows as expected. What I want is how to choose only a couple or single one of them, could it be by specifying the index of the item in datatable? or by the SQL query?

bean :

```
public JcalendarController getSelectedUser() {
    return selectedday;
}

public void setSelectedUser(JcalendarController selectedday) {
    this.selectedday = selectedday;
}

List<String> user_spinner_list = new ArrayList<String>();
List<JcalendarController> calendarlist = new ArrayList<JcalendarController>();

public void delete() {
    System.out.println("JadminBeans >> delete() ---------- id= ");
    JcalendarDAO.deleteDay(selectedday);
}

public List<JcalendarController> getMessages() {
    System.out.println("List<JcalendarController> getMessages()");
    calendarlist = JcalendarDAO.getdays();
    return calendarlist;
}

public long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public int getDay() {
    return day;
}

public void setDay(int day) {
    this.day = day;
}

public String getText() {
    return text;
}

public void setText(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public UploadedFile getFile() {
    return file;
}

public void setFile(UploadedFile file) {
    this.file = file;
}

//--------------------------------------------------------------------------
//---------------------------- user_spinner() ----------------------------//
public List<String> user_spinner() {
    System.out.println("List<JcalendarBeans> user_spinner()");

    user_spinner_list = JcalendarDAO.AllUsarname_spinner();
    return user_spinner_list;
}

//---------------------------- ImageUpload() ----------------------------//
public void ImageUpload() {
    JcalendarController CC = new JcalendarController(this.username, this.day, this.file);
    System.out.println(this.username + " " + this.day + " " + this.file);
    calendarlist.add(CC);
    JcalendarDAO.add_image_DAO(CC);
}

//---------------------------- TextUpload() ----------------------------//
public void TextUpload() {
    JcalendarController CC = new JcalendarController(this.username, this.day, this.text);
    System.out.println(this.username + " " + this.day + " " + this.text);
    calendarlist.add(CC);
    JcalendarDAO.add_text_DAO(CC);
}
```

DAO :

```
public static List<JcalendarController> getdays() {

    List<JcalendarController> ccs = new ArrayList<JcalendarController>();

    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("select * from calendar");

        while (rs.next()) {
            JcalendarController cc = new JcalendarController();
            cc.setId(rs.getLong("id"));
            cc.setDay(rs.getInt("day"));
            cc.setText(rs.getString("text"));
            cc.setUsername(rs.getString("username"));

        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return ccs;
}
```

XHTML

```
<p:dataTable value="#{Jcalendar.messages}" var="o" paginator="true" selection="#{Jcalendar.selectedUser}"
             rowKey="#{o.id}" style="margin-bottom:20px"
             paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
             rowsPerPageTemplate="24,48,144">

    <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Data showing from database" />
    </f:facet>

    <p:column selectionMode="single" />
    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value=" Id" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.id}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Day" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.day}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Text" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.text}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Username" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputText value="#{o.username}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Image" />
        </f:facet>

        <h:outputLink value="DisplayImage?id=#{o.id}" target="_blank">
            <h:graphicImage value="DisplayImage?id=#{o.id}" width="50" height="50"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:outputLink>
    </p:column>

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton value="Delete" action="#{Jcalendar.delete()}" ajax="false" update=":form:msgs"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

Comment: Posting a snippet of your code will be Helpful .

Comment: you can handle your `ccs` in a Handler class and extract the info you want to display in another list and use this new list into your `jsf` code.

Comment: You have a critical business logic in a getter method `getMessages()` which is plain wrong - that costly service method is being executed multiple times causing the same SQL statement to be executed on the database several times. You are already using a rich component library PrimeFaces. Use its [lazy data model](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml) instead - [`org.primefaces.model.LazyDataModel<T>`](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/api/5.1/org/primefaces/model/LazyDataModel.html) that will also help you load the list of rows from the database lazily.

Comment: What is `JcalendarDAO.getdays();`? It is not available in the DAO code you trying to show. The only thing in the DAO is `getAllUsers()` which never called from the managed bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatable will show the values of the *messages* property, so whatever is in the list returned by the *getMessages()* will be rendered inside the table.

For what concerns you question, it is best to make a DAO method and return from the DB only the needed records, putting it in your words, use the SQL.

One optimization hint, you should avoid using any logic inside your *getter* methods as during the life-cycle of a single request, it can be called multiple times. In your case it would contact a DB upon every call. You can check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times) to learn more, and find a better way to initialize your list.